# Understanding Generics in Object Initialization

Tags: java, generics, object, initialization

I have a basic question about generics in Java: what is difference between the following two initializations of a map?

```
        Map<String, String> maplet1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Map<String, String> maplet2 = new HashMap();
```

I understand the the first initialization is specifying the generics in the object construction, but I don't understand the underlying ramifications of doing this, rather than the latter object construction (maplet2). In practice, I've always seen code use the maplet1 construction, but I don't understand where it would be beneficial to do that over the other.

Comment: What makes you think there is a difference?

Comment: There is no functional difference.  the benefit is it does not cause a compiler warning so you don't have to sort "real" raw type warnings from "sloppy syntax" raw type warnings.

Comment: But note that @Affe's comment is only true for a no-arg constructor. Consider that this compiles: `Map<String, String> maplet2 = new HashMap(mapOfIntsToLongs);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second `Map` is assigned to a raw type and will cause a compiler warning. You can simply use the first version to eliminate the warning.

For more see: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

The first one is type-safe.

You can shorthand the right side by using the [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7567) `<>`. This operator infers the type parameters from the left side of the assignment.

`Map<String, String> maplet2 = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 1):

Lets understand the concept of Erasure. At RUNTIME `HashMap<String, String>()` and `HashMap()` are the same represented by HashMap.

The process of converting `HashMap<String,String>` to `HashMap` (Raw Type) is called Erasure.

Without the use of Generics , you have to cast , say the value in the Map , to String Explicitly every time.

The use of Generics forces you to Eliminate cast.

If you don't use Generics , there will be high probability that a Future Developer might insert another type of Object which will cause      `ClassCastException`